# Having issue with storing ip adress in MySQL db table

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Getting users ip adress with this piece of code. I have unsigned int field for ip's in my db table

```
   <?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //proxy check
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    $ip = ip2long($ip);
    ?>
```

Testing website in local server. The problem is, getting  '63177408abbad957ed13ae1a2dd3e0b3ed47bd0b48ffcb362' after ip2long conversion. Tried

```
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip = ip2long($ip);
```

too. Still no success. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're most likely on a 32bit install of PHP, which is corrupting the IP address. Try to do the conversion inside mysql, which doesn't suffer the problem:

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string('127.0.0.1');
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (ip) VALUES (INET_ATON('$ip'));";
```

The other alternative is to force PHP to treat it as an unsigned integer, as per the Notes on the [ip2long man page](http://php.net/ip2long): `$ip = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ip));`

As well, remember that IPv6 will be widespread "any day now", and you'll need to use a 128bit integer to store those values (which MySQL doesn't support - it'd have to be two 64bit bigints at least).

Comment: That's the ipv6 version of 127.0.0.1